# SMS Count based on number of characters

Tags: java, android, math

I am trying to create sms counter for app. It ran good for first couple of test runs but suddenly its no behaving the way it should.

What I want to do is get number of sms to be sent based on number of characters entered in EditText.

0 Characters = 0 (SMS COUNT)
160 Characters = 1 (SMS COUNT)
161 Characters = 2 (SMS COUNT)
320 Characters = 2 (SMS COUNT)
321 Characters = 3 (SMS COUNT)

Basically one sms can contain 160 characters. I tried same thing on jsfiddle and its working fine. Check here ---> [JS Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/13ntk474/4/)

**CODE SNIPPET**

I tried posting here, but SO just keep showing CODE NOT FORMATTED ERROR. Please find code on pastebin.

[Pastebin Link](http://pastebin.com/iH8dUiY9)

**LOGCAT**

```
http://pastebin.com/wb1xm7fj
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: How does it behave instead of how you expect/need it to?

Comment: For the first part it behaves properly. When 0 characters it shows number of sms as 0. From 1 to 160 characters it shows number of sms as 1. But when characters are 161 it should show number of sms as 2 but its showing it as 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your code arises because you are dividing `int`s prior to calling `Math.ceil`: `161/160 == 1`, not `1.00625`. Since, `Math.ceil(1) == 1`, it is effectively a no-op to call `Math.ceil`.

The trivial fix to your existing code would be to write the division as

```
msgChar / 160.0
```

which forces `msgChar` to be upcast to a double, so this would behave like you had expected.

You don't need to use `Math.ceil` to round the result of a division up: if you add `denominator-1` to a positive numerator before dividing, the result will be rounded upwards to the next integer:

```
int msgCount = (numChars + 159) / 160;
```

[Ideone demo](http://ideone.com/rNLAx6)

Comment: That works. Thanks for the help.. Just for information. Can you tell me why Math.ceil is not giving desired output?

Comment: It's because of how integer arithmetic works - you are dividing two integers *before* the `Math.ceil`, so it is already "floored" - `161/160 == 1`, not `1.00625`. It would work if you used `msgChar / 160.0`.

Comment: It worked on jsfiddle so I thought it would work in the app too. Thanks for the help mate.

Comment: JS != Java. JS only has 1 numeric type - `number` - which is a floating point number.

Comment: Cool.. I didn't knew Math class would differ so much between js and java.

Comment: Again: JS != Java. You will get a lot fewer nasty surprises if you start from a position of not expecting them to do the same thing :)

Comment: great... now what will the limits be if you have emoji's also?